# Joining Tables in MySQL (slow)

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to save some data in 2 separate tables and then join these with a reference table.

My data looks like this (a search query and a page-URL):

```
[
['widget', 'www.example.com/widgets'],
['blue widget', 'www.example.com/blue-widgets'],
['red widget', 'www.example.com/widgets'],
['widget', 'www.example.com/green-widgets'],
['orange widget', 'www.example.com/widgets'],
]
```

As you can see, some of search queries are assigned to more than one page, with this in mind as well as some other client-side performance reasons I want to split the search-queries and page-urls into separate tables but keep track of which search-query, belongs to which page-url.

To do this, so far, I have the following 2 tables (the unique_key columns are just hashes to stop duplicates being added):

```
CREATE TABLE queries (
        id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        query VARCHAR(400) collate utf8_bin,
        unique_key varchar(100) unique,
        PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE pages (
        id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        page VARCHAR(2083),
        unique_key varchar(100) unique,
        PRIMARY KEY (id));

insert into queries (query, unique_key) values 
('widget', '1234'),
('widgets', '1233'),
('blue widget', '3243'), 
('red widget', '5432'),
('green widget', '4642');

insert into pages (page, unique_key) values 
('www.example.com/widgets', '7895'),
('www.example.com/widgets-1', '4569'),
('www.example.com/widgets-2', '4568'),
('www.example.com/widgets-3', '1254'),
('www.example.com/widgets-4', '6527');
```

Then, in order to construct the pivot table that relates queries to pages, I'm doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE page_query_join (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    query_id int,
    page_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id));

insert into page_query_join (query_id, page_id)
                    values ((select id from queries where query='widget' limit 1), (select id from pages where page='www.example.com/widgets' limit 1)) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query_id=query_id
```

This is all done in a Python script where I basically create the hash key insert all the search-queries in one loop and then insert all the page-urls in another loop and then loop back round a final time and do the final query to join them.

The full function for this final look-up looks like this:

```
def add_query_page_join(self, data):
    sql = '''insert into page_query_join (query_id, page_id)
                values ((select id from queries where query=%s limit 1), (select id from pages where page=%s limit 1)) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query_id=query_id'''
    try:
        # Execute the SQL command
        self.cursor.executemany(sql, data)
        # Commit your changes in the database
        self.db.commit()
        #return self.cursor.lastrowid
    except Exception as e:
        # Rollback in case there is any error
        self.db.rollback()
    finally:
        self.db.close()
```

The `data` variable looks like this:

```
data = [
['widget', 'www.example.com/widgets'],
['blue widget', 'www.example.com/blue-widgets'],
['red widget', 'www.example.com/widgets'],
['widget', 'www.example.com/green-widgets'],
['orange widget', 'www.example.com/widgets'],
]
```

My data variable is passing 1,000 items at a time but I have about 1 million to do in total, per day. My current version is taking a few hours to complete.

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of either the joining table query or just the way I'm adding everything to the tables (maybe there is a way to insert into all 3 tables at once?)

Appreciate the help - anything missing let me know.

**Update**
Explain on the `join` query:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | NULL    | NULL | NULL          | NULL  | NULL    | NULL  | NULL | No tables used |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | pages   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL  | NULL    | NULL  | 8641 | Using where    |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | queries | ref  | query         | query | 768     | const |    1 | Using where    |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------------+
```

**Example demo:**
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v9ZJR6UwHqRv36qobkGxsv/1

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243669/discussion-on-question-by-adders-joining-tables-in-mysql-slow).

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are doing, but you clearly need

```
queries: INDEX(query, id)  -- This seems to exist
pages: INDEX(page, id)     -- Definitely missing
```

But, since `page` is too big to be indexed, consider changing `unique_hash` to be the `PRIMARY KEY` (and completely get rid of the current `id`).

Meanwhile, you have a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`; do you care which item you get?

Comment: I think the page column is too big for an index

Comment: @Adders - Does `unique_key` provide a uniqueness test for `page`/`query`?

Comment: Yea, that's right, I just hash the query/page

Answer (score 0):

Elaboration:

I assume you've loaded your data into a table called widget_url_pairs. Here's a mock-up...

```
USE test;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS widget_url_pairs;

CREATE TABLE widget_url_pairs
(widget VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
,url VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(widget,url)
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO widget_url_pairs VALUES
('widget', 'www.example.com/widgets'),
('blue widget', 'www.example.com/blue-widgets'),
('red widget', 'www.example.com/widgets'),
('widget', 'www.example.com/green-widgets'),
('orange widget', 'www.example.com/widgets');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS widgets;

CREATE TABLE widgets
(widget_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,widget VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO widgets (widget) SELECT DISTINCT widget FROM widget_url_pairs;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS urls;

CREATE TABLE urls
(url_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,url VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO urls(url) SELECT DISTINCT url FROM widget_url_pairs;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS widget_url;

CREATE TABLE widget_url 
(widget_id INT NOT NULL
,url_id INT NOT NULL
);


INSERT IGNORE INTO widget_url
SELECT DISTINCT w.widget_id
              , u.url_id
           FROM widget_url_pairs wu 
           JOIN widgets w 
             ON w.widget = wu.widget
           JOIN urls u
             ON u.url = wu.url;
             
ALTER TABLE widget_url ADD PRIMARY KEY (widget_id,url_id);

SELECT w.widget
     , u.url 
  FROM widgets w 
  JOIN widget_url wu 
    ON wu.widget_id = w.widget_id 
  JOIN urls u 
    ON u.url_id = wu.url_id;
+---------------+-------------------------------+
| widget        | url                           |
+---------------+-------------------------------+
| blue widget   | www.example.com/blue-widgets  |
| orange widget | www.example.com/widgets       |
| red widget    | www.example.com/widgets       |
| widget        | www.example.com/widgets       |
| widget        | www.example.com/green-widgets |
+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: `www.example.com/widgets` and `widget` are listed twice so it wouldn't be a unique id - If I'm following along correctly

Comment: Ignore me, I wasn't fully understanding. I'll test this tonight

Comment: Ok, tested. Firstly, thanks for your help. However, this is actually slower than my version :/

Comment: Fair enough; I imagine that this would take about 5 minutes, so if your methods faster, that sounds like a winner

Comment: Testing this on my own machine (nothing fancy) on a widget_url_pair data set of half a million rows (a cross product of 50 distinct widgets and 10000 distinct urls) , the entire operation took 30 seconds.